# how to default a value to "Select Question" in select in Angular 8?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-select

how to default a value to “Select Question” in select in Angular 8?

this is my html code below

```
 <label for="question" class="sr-only">Security Question</label>
        <select id="question" formControlName='drpDwnctrl' [value]='0' class="w-100 mb2" [(ngModel)]="selectedQuestion"
          (ngModelChange)="errMsg = ''">
          <option disabled value="0">Select Question</option>
          <option *ngFor="let question of questionList" [ngValue]="question.questionText">{{question.questionText}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

Comment: If you are using formControlName no need to ngModel: ```<option *ngFor="let question of questionList" [ngValue]="question">``` and  ```form = new FormGroup({
    drpDwnctrl: new FormControl(this.questionList[2]) // default vlue
  });```

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding 'selected' to the option you want to default to. The 'selected' will make it the default option, and the 'disabled' will prevent users from selecting it.

Example: `<option disabled selected value="0">Select Question</option>`